# Run WScript.exe using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, windows-server-2012, wscript.shell

I want to run `.wsf` script using `VB.NET` so I am using below code.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("WScript.exe", Chr(34) + scriptFilePath + Chr(34) + " " + argument)
```

It is not working if I call it from the code but If I use the same thing using `cmd` then It is working fine.
CMD i.e.

```
WScript.exe "D:\Project\Test-File.wsf" hello
```

Can someone please help me to sort out this issue? I want to run it on the production server (Windows Server 2012).

Comment: Which is the executing/target directory. Is WScript.exe reachable? (the path of the exe is inside PATH env variables)

Comment: @Babbillumpa Yes, else it shouldn't work with `cmd` also.

Comment: @Babbillumpa I observed that when I run it through Visual Studio then it is working fine but after hosting on `IIS`, It is not working.